# Stripe connect http function firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments

I have created a cloud function with the following:
I'm trying to make an app/platform where a user can sign up for an account using Stripe Connect. I have a database with Firestore and the backend is using firebase cloud functions and nodejs.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51XXX');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.createStripeUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    var auth_code = stripe.oauth.token({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: req.query.code,
});return res.send("Please close this page")

}
)
```

My problem is that I have an error where the req, res is. I don't know why there is an error, is the request wrong? What can I do so that I get no error and fix the problem?
[image]

If I hover on req, I get this message

```
(parameter) req: any
Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

I am using typescript

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hi, I just uploaded a picture of what it looks like on my console, the error is the req, res. I don't know why there is an error.

Comment: Can you hover on `req` and take a screenshot of the error? Are you using TS or (ESLint) by chance ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Hello there, I have just edited it. I don't know how to take a screenshot while hovering but I copied the message of the error I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using Typescript and `req`, `res` are implicitly of type `any`. You can import `Request` and `Response` from Express as shown below:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express"

export const createStripeUser = functions.https.onRequest((req: Request, res: Response) => {
 // ...
})
```

And yes, explicitly adding `any` like `(req: any, res: any)` will remove that error too but that isn't the best thing to do.